# Could an AVR ISP connector be reused to add SPI-Interfaced memories without programing the controller?

Tags: avr, spi, atmega, isp

I have no previous experience designing AVR-Compatible hardware.
I have a board which uses an ATMega 2560 and has a SPI bus which is already used by a SD adapter. After some datasheet reading, I realized ISP connectors implement the SPI bus too and I was thinking if it could be used to add some external storage in form of EEPROM or flash to complement its internal memory.

My main concern is, basically that ISP exists to reprogram the device and therefore I don't know if it suits the purpose I would like to give it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ATMega2560 has only one hardware SPI controller. This interface shares the same device pins as its ISP interface. A special sequence is applied when the reset signal is asserted during programming to enter ISP mode.

Assuming the "SD adapter" on your board is using the hardware SPI controller, then the pins on the ISP connector are the same pins already being used for the SD card.

You could potentially add additional devices to that SPI bus by using seperate chip-select signals, however I can't say whether this will impact the ability to use the SD card as that will depend on what hardware you have and what it does.

Alternatively, the UART controllers of the ATMega2560 can be configured to operate as hardware SPI master interfaces, albeit with some differences in the registers used to control them. As there are four UARTs on this chip, there is plenty of opportunity to make a second, third or fourth SPI controller to use for your external memory.